# Why is UDP + a software reliable ordering system faster than TCP?

Tags: networking, tcp, udp

Some games today use a network system that transmits messages over UDP, and ensures that the messages are reliable and ordered.

For example, [RakNet](http://www.jenkinssoftware.com/) is a popular game network engine. It uses only UDP for its connections, and has a whole system to ensure that packets can be reliable and ordered if you so choose.

My basic question is, what's up with that? Isn't TCP the same thing as ordered, reliable UDP? What makes it so much slower that people have to basically reinvent the wheel?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### General/Specialisation

1. TCP is a general purpose reliable system
2. UDP +whatever is a special purpose reliable system.

Specialized things are usually better than general purpose things for the thing they are specialized.

### Stream / Message

1. TCP is stream-based
2. UDP is message-based

Sending discrete gaming information maps usually better to a message-based paradigm. Sending it through a stream is possible but horribly ineffective. If you want to reliably send a huge amount of data (File transfer), TCP is quite effective. That's why Bit-torrent use UDP for control messages and TCP for data sending.

Answer (score 14):

We switched from reliable to unreliable in "league of legends" about a year ago because of several advantages which have since proven to be true:

1) Old information becomes irrelevant.  If I send a health packet and it doesn't arrive... I don't want to have to wait for that same health packet to resend when I know its changed.

2) Order is sometimes not necessary.  If I'm sending different messages to different systems it may not be necessary to get those messages in order.  I don't force the client to wait for in-order messages.

3) Unreliable doesn't get backed up with messages... ie waiting for acknowledgements which means you can resolve loss spikes much more quickly.

4) You can control resends when necessarily more efficiently.  Such as repacking something that didn't send into another packet.  (TCP does repack but you can do it more efficiently with knowledge about how your program works.)

5) Flow control of message such as throwing away messages that are less relevant when the network suddenly spikes.  The network system can choose not to resend less relevant messages when you have a loss spike.  With TCP you'd still have a queue of messages that are trying to resend which may be lower priority.

6) Smaller header packet... don't really need to say much about that.

Answer (score 4):

There's much more of a difference between UDP and TCP than just reliability and sequencing:

At the heart of the matter is the fact that UDP is *connectionless* while TCP is *connected*. This simple difference leads to a host of other differences that I'm not going to be able to reasonbly summarize here. You can read the analysis below for much more detail.

[TCP - UDP Comparative Analysis](http://www.laynetworks.com/Comparative%20analysis_TCP%20Vs%20UDP.htm)

Answer (score 3):

The answer in in my opinion the two words: "Congestion control".

TCP goes to great lengths to manage the bandwidth of the path - to use the most of it, but to ensure that there is space for other applications. This is a very hard task, and inherently it is not possible to use 100% of the bandwidth 100% of the time.

With UDP, on the other hand, one can make their own protocol to send the packets onto the wire as fast as they want - this makes the protocol very unfriendly to other applications, but can gain more "performance" short-term. On the other hand, it is with high probability that if the conditions are appropriate, this kind of protocols might contribute to [congestion collapse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Congestive_collapse).

Answer (score 1):

TCP is a stream-oriented protocol, whereas UDP is a message-oriented protocol. Hence TCP does more than just reliability and ordering. See [this post](http://www.sharpprogrammer.com/networking/comparison-tcp-and-udp-protocol/) for more details. Basically, the RakNet developers added the reliability and ordering while still keeping it as a message-oriented protocol, and so the result was more lightweight than TCP (which has to do more).

Answer (score 0):

This little article is old, but it's still pretty true when it comes to games.  It explains the two protocols, and the havoc these folks went trying to develop a multiplayer internet game. "X-Wing vs Tie Fighter"

[Lessons Learned (The Internet Sucks)](http://www.gamasutra.com/features/19990903/lincroft_05.htm)

There is one caveat to this though, I run/develop a multiplayer game, and I've used both.  UDP was much better for my app, but alot of people couldn't play with UDP.  Routers and such blocked the connections.  So I changed to the "reliable" TCP.  Well... Reliable?  I don't think so.  You send a packet, no errors, you send another and it crashes (exception) in the middle of the packet.  Now which packets made it?  So you end up writing a reliable protocol ON TOP OF tcp, to simulate UDP - but continuously establish a new connection when it crashes.  Take about inefficient.

UDP + Stop and wait ARW = good

UDP + Sliding Window Protocol = better

TCP + Sliding Window Protocol with reconnection? = Worthless bulkware. (IMHO)

The other side effect is multi-threaded applications.  TCP works well for a chat room type thing, since each room can be it's own thread.  A room can hold 60-100 people and it runs fine, as the Room thread contains the Sockets for each participant.

UDP on the other hand is best served (IMO) by one thread, but when you get the packet, you have to parse it to figure out who it came from (via info sent or RemoteEndPoint), then pass that data to the chatroom thread in a threadsafe manner.

Actually, you have to do the same with TCP, but only on connect.

Last point.  Remember that TCP will just error out and kill the connection at anytime, but you can reconnect in about .5 seconds and send the same information.  Most bizzare thing I've ever worked with.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the exception that was thrown when you used TCP? I would definitely blame your code and not the TCP layer for that, as it sounds a little ridiculous. Thanks for pointing out the Sliding Window Protocol though, I hadn't heard of that and it's an interesting algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

UDP have a lower reliability give it more reliability by making it send a message and wait for respond if no respond came it resend the message.

Comment: There are six existing answers, some which have been validated by the community, most of which offer far more detail than this. While we're happy you're anxious to contribute to the community, please focus your time on questions where you have new information to add.